# How to print frequency on boxplot - ggplot - R

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

This is my Dataframe

```
X color   cut      carrat
1   E    Ideal     0.23
2   J    Premiun   0.34
3   E    Ideal     0.23
...
```

I want to create a box plot of my column var "cut".

Here is the code for what I want to do...

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut)) + geom_boxplot()
```

However, it isn't working properly as it's asking that aesthetics var "y", is missing.

It's because I am not providing a second var to aes, what's the second var I have to supply? Because I only need in the x's edge the different values my var "cut" can takes and in the Y's edge the frequendy of it.

Thanks.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to accomplish.  You'd like a box plot of the frequency of the "cut" column...but that column is qualitative.  Boxplots typically visualize the five-number summary of a quantitative data.  (ie, the quartiles and outliers).  To show the frequency of the different cuts, I think a bar plot might be more appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A boxplot needs a y variable because it is illustrating a distribution. The count of rows by cut will not be a distribution but just one number per cut. Here are the counts of each cut:

```
> table(diamonds$cut)

     Fair      Good Very Good   Premium     Ideal 
     1610      4906     12082     13791     21551
```

That information can not be shown in a box plot. Instead, you could use a bar chart like so:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut)) +
  geom_bar()
```

Which produces this chart:

[image: bar chart]

Or here is the code of a boxplot of cut and carat, as an example:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, y = carat)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

And the chart:

[image: boxplot]

So the boxplot is showing the mean, range and quartiles of the carat column by each level of cut.

Answer (score 2):

The below code will do the job:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, y=carat))
p <- p + geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = "blue", fill="grey85")
p <- p + labs(title = "Diamonds carats")
show(p)
```

a boxplot is a grouping of some data distributions, therefore you must provide the data whose distribution you want to boxplot. The `x` aesthetics must represent the type, the `y` must represent the data set.

[image]

Comment: Perfect, it was a problem about what I want to represent, thanks.